# Python xlrd and xlwt does not append to existing xls

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt

I want to append columns to the same xls for every run. Its not getting appended using my existing code.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy


wb_in = xlrd.open_workbook('~/new.xls', 'r+')
sheet_name = wb_in.sheet_names()[0]
ws_in = wb_in.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)

wb_out = xlwt.Workbook()
ws_out = wb_out.add_sheet(sheet_name)   # Use the same sheet name


f = open('~/count.txt', 'r+')

data = f.readlines() # read all lines at once
for i in range(len(data)):
  row = data[i].split()  # This will return a line of string data, you may need to convert to other formats depending on your use case

  for j in range(len(row)):
    ws_out.write(i, j, row[j])  # Write to cell i, j

wb_out.save('~/new' + '.xls')
f.close()
```

Its getting the sheet name correctly. But is not appending.

count .txt is :

```
Selissues  11
Genissues 68
Noissues  7
Otherissues  13
Total  99999
Pruning/OtherEfficiency .58064516129032258064
CSEfficiency .38888888888888888888
```

Want the excel to look like :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems. One, you aren't copying the existing contents of `wb_in` to `wb_out`. You're importing `xlutils.copy`, but not using it.

Second, you're writing out the data always beginning from row `0`. This means you'll always be overwriting whatever is already there.

The following should resolve both of those issues. Note that `wb_out` is being set to a copy of `wb_in`, and that when writing to `ws_out`, the row number is being offset by `ws_in.nrows`, the number of rows that already existed in `ws_in`:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

wb_in = open_workbook('~/new.xls', 'r+')
ws_in = wb_in.sheet_by_index(0)

wb_out = copy(wb_in)
ws_out = wb_out.get_sheet(0)

f = open('~/count.txt', 'r+')

data = f.readlines()

for i in range(len(data)):
    row = data[i].split()

    for j in range(len(row)):
        ws_out.write(ws_in.nrows + i, j, row[j].strip())

wb_out.save('~/new.xls')
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank u :) it works now..but is there a way to add just the columns everytime? This excel will be updated every week.